# PHP Mysql insert statement from a function

Tags: php, mysql

This code gets values from a database and forms a sms template and then passes the moble number and message to webservice to send the sms. It's part of a function wall().....

```
     $name = $resultarr['name'];
     $amount = $resultarr['amount'];
     $transaction_id = $resultarr['trans_id'];
     $date = $resultarr['time_paid'];

    //message template
    $message = "Dear $name we have received $amount from you. MPESA transaction Id $transaction_id on $date.";

    $mobilenumber = $resultarr['msisdn']; // get mobile number from array
    $message_sent = $message;

    $serviceArguments = array(
            "mobilenumber" => $mobilenumber,
            "message" => $message_sent
    );

    $client = new SoapClient("http://59.38.606.10:8080/smsengine/smsws?WSDL");

    $result = $client->process($serviceArguments);

 grabdetails($message_sent, $mobilenumber);

    return $result;

} 
//I call the function wall() to send sms         

  wall();

  $perm = wall();
  $status = $sperm->return; //outputing the status
  // Here I want to capture the $status variable and put it in a db below
  echo "$status";


 function grabdetails($messagee, $mobno)
 {

$message_sent = $messagee;
$mobilenumber = $mobno;


$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$dbname = "smsdb";

   // Create connection


  // Check connection

   $sql = "INSERT INTO smsdb (sms_text, receiver_number, time_sent, status)
      VALUES
         ('$message_sent', '$mobilenumber', NOW(), $status )";
```

Question is how do I grab $status ind insert it into the db since its not in the function? Kindly. help, anyone?

Comment: What exactly is the issue here?  When you have the "status" value, execute an `INSERT` statement with that value.  You can do that directly in the lines following where you get that value, or write a function to do it and call that function after you get that value.  It's not clear what the problem is.

Comment: Hello @David so you are saying I can just insert $status at that exact point where I am echoing it out? That is                                              $sql = "INSERT INTO smsdb ( status)
      VALUES
         ( '$status' )";        Thereafer I can insert the other variables?

Answer (score 0):

The code above is not complete, but I assume that the function on top where you do `$client = new SoapClient("http://59.38.606.10:8080/smsengine/smsws?WSDL");` is actually the wall function. If so, then what that function returns, i.e. `$result` actually has the status you need. So with this code snippet (assuming $sperm is a typo and should actually be $perm, the response from the wall function), you get the response from `wall()`, which is an object and has the status you need.

```
$perm = wall();
$status = $sperm->return; //outputing the status
// Here I want to capture the $status variable and put it in a db below
echo "$status";
```

If that's right, then before calling `grabdetails` in the wall function, you actually have the status and you can send it to the function like this:

```
grabdetails($message_sent, $mobilenumber, $result->return);
```

And then change the definition of the `grabdetails` to receive the status as well and use it in the DB insert.

Comment: Thanks for the direction, let me try it out. Will update on the out come. @trajchevska